# How to convert comma delimited String to List of T in Core Java

Tags: java

"first time long time" as they say on the radio talk shows...

I'm trying to parse a delimited property into a List.  Simple enough, but for some reason I can't figure how to do this in a generic fashion using only Core Java.  By generic, I mean the type of List to create may be a List< String >, List< Integer >, or List< Double >.  My latest stab at it below gives runtime exceptions with non-Strings because I'm trying to cast from String to e.g. Double which is not allowed.  Any help is appreciated.

```
public static <T> void parsePropsToList(String propName, String delim, List<T> listToFill){
   //This is paired down for convenience - assume getSplitList correctly parses to List<String>
   List<String> stringList = PropsManager.getSplitList(propName, delim);
   for(String s : stringList){
       listToFill.add((T)s);
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to use Double.valueOf(string) to get a Double from a String.

Comment: Many thanks, Sbodd, Pierre, this has really been bugging me.  I went with Pierre's solution b/c I think my method already has too many args, so now that I can construct the List inside my method, all I have to do is pass in the propName, delim and class name, and return a populated List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the Class in your function, something like;

```
public static <T> void parsePropsToList(
  String propName,
  String delim,
  List<T> listToFill,
  Class<T> clazz)
```

then using the [reflection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) of *clazz*, get the [Constructor](http://72.5.124.55/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) having one **String** for its argument, split your propName with delim and, for each substring, invoke a new instance of T using the previous constructor. put this new instance into listToFill and return this list at then.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java throws out generic type information at runtime, you need to pass something in to your method that'll let you convert from the property string to the correct type.

I think the easiest thing to do would be to add a Parser parameter to your method:

```
public interface Parser<T> {
  public T parse(String value);
}

static <T> void parsePropsToList(String propName, String delim, List<T> listToFill, Parser<T> parser) {
  String value;
  //extract value from property
  listToFill.add(parser.parse(value));
}
```